# How to define aggregate roots from a relational model in order to use it for DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot, aggregates

Ive looked quite a while at others posts in there relativly to aggregates roots. It seem that i don't understand at all how to define in the right way aggregates roots. I saw answers such as aggregates roots might not be aggregates roots and vice versa. I am a bit confused. The problem is that i have relational model in head but i know that DDD won't go that way.

Is there a way to define aggregate roots from a relation model ?

Example, if you have a **journal** that **hold journal entries** which **each hold tasks, problems, and notes**

How would you define the aggregates roots ? Is the root a **journal** ? but that may cause problems if you want to access notes, problems and tasks. So are thoses also aggregates roots which hold reference to journal entries ?

Its something hard to understand and i would like to have some more clarification.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with you that the concept of aggregate roots can be confusing until you get your mind around it. Like most other concepts it gets easier with practice, working it through a few times.

The point of the aggregate is to simplify object traversal for some external obect, *in the context of one or more use case(s)*. You have to start *somewhere* to satisfy a business requirement, and if you find that you are largely needing a Journal, it's like that it should in fact be an aggregate root. In most domains that aren't trivial, you will find it useful to have more than one aggregate root. There is nothing supernatural about the starting object for a use case. You just need to start somewhere.

But again, the point is to simplify object traversal, which simplifies your system. So if Journal is in fact a useful starting point, make all of your calls to Journal first. If a particular use case will wind up needing Tasks, Money, Time or any other useful things, the calling program gets those things by asking Journal, and only Journal. The other objects are part of the Journal aggregate root, for this use case.

For other use cases, it may be more natural and therefore useful for Task to be the starting point, and so you may have a Task aggregate root too, which will likely overlap your Journal aggregate root of use cases. But you ask Task and only Task to satisfy the request (be the only reference that the calling program needs to know about)

Your relational db can and will stay relational of course. But by having your object model evolve to look at requests from an aggregate (starting point object) point of view, your requests from the db will wind up being simpler.

Lay out a use case (or two) and try and work it through. Ask questions within the context of the use case if you like.

HTH,
Berryl

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer. I think i get the idea now.. however i need some clarification about what you said "But you ask Task and only Task to satisfy the request" what did you want to say ? If i understand the service layer contains many use cases related to one entity but that may be possible to need 2 repository in our service layer.

Comment: Also about aggregates roots, i guess i won't call journal a lots often because it is only used as a starting point for someone.. the only entity that gonna be heavly used is the JournalEntry which gonna be added a lots. But i don't want to end up with 3 methods each time in each of the use cases. Such as Journal j = JournalRepository.Find(...) and JournalEntry je =JournalEntryRepository.Find(...) etc.

Comment: @Rushino. Can you lay out a use case? The DDD bits will make more sense once they are in the context of your use case. For example, my business needs JournalEntries in order to ....

Comment: Well my business need journalentries to tell what have been done in a project for a specified amount of time.

Comment: Also i must be able to add new entries then add attached tasks, notes, problems for each.

Comment: IEnumerable<JournalEntry> GetEntriesFor(Project p, DateRange r);

Comment: Project.Add(JournalEntry je, IEnumerabel<Notes> notes, IEnumerabel<Problems problems);

Comment: There is no project. Would be journal entry then ?

Comment: sorry if i used the word project in my use case check the model from the first post the use case is rather straightforward. Journal hold entries which each hold notes problems and tasks

Comment: If i understand because were going to use the entry repository (or would intent to) it mean that it is an aggregate root? But inst your going to end up with too many aggregates roots ?

Comment: Also In order to be part of an aggregate there must be also rules to maintain the state of the whole aggregate valid that why you pass by its root to make operations and that the collection is read only?

Comment: Rushino - I'm at a loss to understand a specific question that has to do with aggregate roots here that I might answer. It might be helpful to take a few of the ideas in your head and turn them into well thought out questions (ones that most reader would understand what is being asked though they might not be able to answer them), even if you don't ask them here on SO. HTH

Comment: Well you provided enough explanation. Its seem a vague topic so i will try something and if i ever get any problems i will get back here. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @Rushino This answer is rather incomplete and the following statement is completely wrong: "But again, the point is to simplify object traversal, which simplifies your system". Aggregate roots have almost nothing to do with simplifying object traversal. Aggregate roots should be modeled regarding their true invariants and consistency boundaries. Have a look at these articles http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/